# Using jquery from parent in a child iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent

i want to use jquery library in a child iframe. Parent window has included jquery library. 
This is the script that included in iframe

```
$p=parent.window.$;
$p(document).ready(function (){
        console.log($p('#bla').val()); 
        console.log($p('#searchedCity').val());
    }
);
```

`$p('#bla').val()` - this I'm trying to get value of input text field that is located in iframe. Now it returns `undefined`

`$p('#searchedCity').val()` - this is value of input text field from parent window. and it returns the right value

when I'm including jquery library directly to the iframe - `$('#bla').val()` works fine.

what am I missing? Can you help me?

Comment: why you do not want to add jquery library in iframe?

Comment: you should load jquery libray in iframe also and try the answer given bewlow by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because your searching for elements `$p('#bla')` `#bla` in parent container. which is not present there..load jquery in current iframe and use `$`..

```
$p=parent.window.$;
$p(document).ready(function (){
    console.log($('#bla').val()); 
    console.log($p('#searchedCity').val());
   }
);
```

and yes you are calling these function when parent's  document is ready which may not work as it should..

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    console.log($('#bla').val()); 
     $p=parent.window.$;
    console.log($p('#searchedCity').val());
   }
);
```

Comment: so there is no way WITHOUT including jquery library directly to the iframe?

Comment: i guess no.... :) ..unless you try getting the iframe textbox value from the parent document where jquery is loaded... without any script in iframe itself..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it does the same but try this :

```
console.log($('#bla', p).val()); 
console.log($('#searchedCity', p).val());
```

Comment: the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$p=parent.window.$;
    $p(document).ready(function (){
        console.log($('#bla').val()); 
        console.log($p('#searchedCity').val());
    }
);
```